# Replacing Existing Google Sheets File via Python

Tags: python, google-api

I have a spreadsheet in Google Drive that I need to replace weekly, without changing the file id (charts are on google data studio).

I can create a new sheet, but not replace the existing file. I have this, but I get an error saying the file can't be found. If I add the folder id, I get an error saying that parents are not directly writable.

```
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly',
          'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file']
store = file.Storage(c_path+'g_credentials_drive.json')
g_creds = store.get()
if not g_creds or g_creds.invalid:
    flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets('client_secret.json', SCOPES)
    g_creds = tools.run_flow(flow, store)
service = build('drive', 'v3', http=g_creds.authorize(Http()))

Folder_id = '***'
fileId = '***'
para = {'name': 'file'}
media = MediaFileUpload('C:/autorun/path/file.xlsx', 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet', resumable=True, chunksize=1048576)
files = service.files().update(fileId=fileId,body=para,media_body=media).execute()

r = requests.patch("https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files/" + fileId + "?uploadType=multipart",
    headers=headers,
    files=files,
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to overwrite the existing Google Spreadsheet with XLSX data on the local PC.
- You want to achieve this using googleapis for python.

#### Modification points:

- From `I have this, but I get an error saying the file can't be found.` and your showing script, in this case, the reason for your current issue might be due to the scopes. In your scopes, `['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file']` is used. In this case, please modify it to `['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']` and test it again.
- If you want to use `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file`, please create a new Spreadsheet by this client with `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file`. By this, you can access the created Spreadsheet. Please be careful about this.
- And, in your script, `files` of `files = service.files().update(fileId=fileId,body=para,media_body=media).execute()` is used at `r = requests.patch("https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files/" + fileId + "?uploadType=multipart", headers=headers, files=files)`.

When these points are reflected in your script, how about the following modification? **In this case, please reauthorize the scope. Please be careful about this.**

#### From:

```
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly',
          'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file']
```

#### To:

```
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
```

And,

#### From:

```
Folder_id = '***'
fileId = '***'
para = {'name': 'file'}
media = MediaFileUpload('C:/autorun/path/file.xlsx', 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet', resumable=True, chunksize=1048576)
files = service.files().update(fileId=fileId,body=para,media_body=media).execute()

r = requests.patch("https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files/" + fileId + "?uploadType=multipart",
    headers=headers,
    files=files,
)
```

#### To:

```
spreadsheetId = "###" # Please set your Spreadsheet ID.
media = MediaFileUpload("C:/autorun/path/file.xlsx", resumable=True, chunksize=1048576)
res = service.files().update(fileId=spreadsheetId, body={'name': 'file'}, media_body=media, supportsAllDrives=True).execute()
print(res)
```

Comment: Thanks for the assist, unfortunately I am still seeing the same can't find the file error

Comment: @santanicopandimonium Thank you for replying. About `unfortunately I am still seeing the same can't find the file error`, I would like to confirm as follows. 1. You change the scope to `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive` and reauthorize the scope? Namely, you reauthorize the scope by removing the file of `c_path+'g_credentials_drive.json'`. How about this? 2. Where is your Spreadsheet?